# hasManyThrough() - Property [price] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel

Items:
 - id
 - user_id

Users:
 - id
 - country_id

Freight prices
 - id
 - country_from_id
 - country_to_id
 - price

#### Item.php

```
public function localPrice()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
       'App\FreightPrice',
       'App\User',
       'id',
       'country_from_id',
       'user_id',
       'country_id'
    );
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

#### User.php

```
public function countryFromId(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\FreightPrice');
}
```

#### FreightPricePrice.php

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I need to get item's "country_from_id", by using "user_id".
This code returns error: "Property [price] does not exist on this collection instance."
Here is query:"select `freight_prices`.*, `users`.`id` from `freight_prices` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `freight_prices`.`country_from_id` where `users`.`id` is null".